# Exceptions are being thrown within try/catch in VS2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, exception

I couldnt find a thread with exactly my problem, so if somebody knows if it has been solved, please forward it to me :)

I am working on Visual C++ 2008, version 9.0.21022.8 RTM. I am creating some testing but visualStudio is always breaking on this exception

```
bool exceptionCaught = false;
try
{
  char* buff = NULL;
  buff[0] = 10;
}
catch (...)
{
  exceptionCaught = true;
}
```

I have unchecked all the boxes in Debugging->Exceptions, I have tried all the options in Tools->Options dialog, in the Debugging section. 
I am using the exception handling /HEa (but anyway, /EHsc doesnt change anything)

This piece of code works perfectly on another computer but even using its configuration my behaviour doesnt change, it keeps breaking all the time...

Is there something i am missing? another option/menu?

Comment: C++ exception handling does not catch [structured exceptions (SEH)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680657%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: "This piece of code works perfectly on another computer" ... but should it? This code is not good, and it is hard to tell what you are even trying to do with it.

Answer (score 2):

Writing through a null pointer is undefined behaviour in C++. There is no reason why it should generate a C++ exception. You can't use the C++ exception model to handle direct writes to invalid addresses.

It probably generates some form of OS error; this can also be called "exception," but it has nothing to do with C++ exceptions.